# Cannot create symbolic link to JavaScriptCore on mac?

Tags: javascript, macos, command-line-interface, bin, javascriptcore

I am trying to use Mac's JavaScriptCore to run some JavaScript scripts without using HTML or a website. When I tried to make a link using `$ sudo ln -s /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/Versions/Current/Resources/jsc /bin/jsc` I got a message saying `ln: /bin/jsc: Operation not permitted`. Does anyone know how to fix this problem? If it's not fixable, should I just install Rhino or install Homebrew and get Google's V8 engine?

Comment: Can you add output of `stat /bin/jsc`?

Comment: @richard it says no such file or directory... and it's not there when I manually navigate into the bin directory either. Should I create it?

Comment: Good, as you are creating it with `ln`. Do you have permission to write to `/bin`? What happens if you try `touch /bin/zzzz`?

Comment: I think the answer may be here http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/196224/unix-ln-s-command-not-permitted-in-osx-el-capitan-beta3 not even root can do somethings, (seems a bit like se-linux, apparmor etc).

Comment: @richard you're right I read the link... should I link the javascriptcore into usr/local/ then?

Comment: Should work. The behaviour of `/bin`, `/usr/bin`, `/usr/local/bin` is defined in the environment variable `PATH`, by default it should include at least these 3 directories. The order only matters if the same name appears in more than 1 place.

Comment: @richard last thing, should i then link it to `usr/local/` or `usr/local/bin`? Or does it really matter?

Comment: should be a `bin` directory. As those are in the `PATH`, therefore `/usr/local/bin`

Answer (score 0):

see https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/196224/unix-ln-s-command-not-permitted-in-osx-el-capitan-beta3

Root is not all powerful any more, so put it in `/usr/local/bin`. In any case you should not be editing `/bin` or `/usr/bin` or other system maintained directories.